# Creating a Latex table, in which the last row is always at the same position and doesn't move even new content is added to the other rows

Tags: latex, row

I want to Create a Latex table, in which the last row is always at the same position and doesn't move even new content is added to the other rows.

[image: ![enter image description here] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtycV.png)]

In the attached figure, the problem is with the 3rd row, when I write a long text the 4th, 5th... rows are moving, and I want the to be always at the same place with a short or a long text (independent of the content).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `tabularray` package, you can specify how height the row should be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={X},
  vlines,
  hlines,
  row{3}={ht=5cm}
}
test\\
test\\
some long textsome long textsome long textsome long textsome long textsome long tsome long textsome long textsome long textsome long textsome long textsome long textsome long text
test\\
test
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```